# JavaScript cannot change image using attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My html code here is to click next and change the graph.
I have put 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, and html file into same file.

My question is that I want to change my graph by the code `$("#page1").attr("src", fname);`.

But it cannot do it at all. It always shows 1.jpg.

````
<script>
var order = new Array('1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg');
var trial = 0; //current trial
document.write("STRING:");
$(document).ready(function(){
 ShowImage(trial);
});

function ShowImage(t) {
 $("#page1").show();
 var N = t+1; //counting from 1
 $(".progress").text('('+N+'/'+order.length+')');
}

function NextImage() {
 current = current + 1;
 $("#page1").hide();
 var fname=order[current];
 $("#page1").attr("src", fname);
 });
 ShowImage(current);
}

</script>

<style> .page {display: none;} </style> 

<div class="page" id="page1">
<img src=1.jpg><br>
<input type=radio name=f1 value=T> T
<input type=radio name=f1 value=F> F <br>
<a href="javascript:NextTrial()">Next</a> 
<span class="progress"></span>
</div>

<div class="page" id="page2">
<h3>All done!</h3>
</div>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're going to change `src` of `<img>` tag, so you should get the `<img>` tag.
in your `html` the `<img>` tag is in `<div id="page1">` so you should use the `find` keyword to get the `<img>` tag and then change the `src` of it.

```
function NextImage() {
 current = current + 1;
 $("#page1").hide();
 var fname=order[current];
 $("#page1").find('img').attr("src", fname);   //this line should find the img tag and then change the src attr
 });
 ShowImage(current);
}
```